# AngularJs - allow only one item to be selected in Table

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angular-ui-bootstrap, smart-table

I am using smart table. I have a logic behind where I only need one item to be selected. My current table code allow multiple lines to be selected.

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
 <table st-safe-src="flow3.dataSet" st-table="flow3.displayed" class="table table-striped">

                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th st-sort="method">Method</th>
                    <th st-sort="sample">Sample</th>
                    <th st-sort="parameters">Parameters</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ui-sortable ng-model="flow3.displayed">
                <tr ng-repeat="row in flow3.displayed track by $index" style="cursor: move;" ng-click="row.selected = !row.selected; flow3.selectRow($event, row)" ng-class="{success: row.selected}">
                    <td>{{row.method.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.sample}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <span ng-repeat="parameter in row.parameters">{{parameter.methodInputParameter.name}} : {{parameter.value}}<br/></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="flow3.removeItem(row)"
                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-round pull-right"
                                ng-disabled="flow3.confirmDisabled">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my JS:

```
 flow3.selectRow = function($event, row) {
        flow3.selectedItem = row; 
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to apply different class to highlight the row?

Comment: Hi  Stanislav. The class of the highlighted row doesn't matter. I just can't have 2 row selected at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the only one `row` with `selected` property set to `true`, you should modify your `selectRow` method to accept the collection of all rows and then de-select all before selecting clicked one:

```js
flow3.selectRow = function($event, row, rows) {
  //de-select all
  angular.forEach(rows, function(r){ r.selected = false; });
  //select clicked
  row.selected = true;
  flow3.selectedItem = row; 
}
```

```html
ng-click="flow3.selectRow($event, row, flow3.dataSet)"
```

If you want to apply different css class to the clicked/selected item you probably can leave your `selectRow` method as is (since we have the selected item as `flow3.selectedItem`) and change the condition in the `ngClass` directive to be (if rows have some unique id property for example):

```html
ng-class="{success: row.id === flow3.selectedItem.id}"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the smart table github page and use guide [here](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/).

In particular the section relevant to your question is 'Select Data Rows'.

Essentially you need to use the st-select-row attribute along with the st-select-mode to configure click within your table row (tr) elements.